# Observe property of a LiveData wrapped object

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I am developing an RPG game for Android. There is a `player` which has n >=0 `spell`s assigned.

**Player.kt**

```kotlin
class Player{
    // spell is on cooldown when value == false
    val _spells = mutableMapOf<Spell, Boolean>() 
    
    // will be assigned _spells later in code
    // When spell is used, I set the value to false and call 
    // spells.postValue(_spells) to trigger observers
    val spells = MutableLiveData<Map<Spell,Boolean>>() 
}
```

In the `CombatViewModel.kt` Im loading the `Player` and `Spell`s from a Room DB.

**CombatViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
class CombatViewModel{
    val player = repository.getActivePlayer()
    val spells = repository.loadSelectedSpells().map{
        // set spells in the player class
        player.value?.setSpells(it)
    }
   
    // now I want to povide an observable variable just for the spells
    // It must be the same reference as in startCombat below
    val spellsWithCooldown = player.value?.spells 

    // is called from Fragment via button
    fun startCombat(){
       viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            // already observed
            player.value!!.setHealthToMax()
            combatRepository.getCombat().setPlayer(player.value!!)
       }
    }
}
```

**CombatFragment.kt**

```kotlin
class CombatFragment : Fragment() {
   combatViewModel.player.observe(){
      // do stuff with player: bin portrait, HP, Exp, etc
   }

   combatViewModel.spellsWithCooldown.observe(){
       // show all available spells
       // change appeariance if on cooldown
   }
}
```

Now the problem is, that I don't get the LiveData from `player.value?.spells` as `player` is not observed yet.

So practically I want to observe a LiveData property of a LiveData wrapped object. I want to set that property at the same time or shortly after the `player` is loaded from DB.

I tried to load the spells within a n:m relationship at the same time with player, but I don't know how to separate this property to not be triggered when some other properties of player change.

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense for Player to be returned wrapped in a LiveData from the repository. A LiveData implies you will be getting new Player instances over time. Do you want to set spells on this player every time there's a new one? Or is there only ever one player?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I need one full instance of Player to be passed to the CombatEngine. And I need some properties (name, level, HP) of this Player instance to be shown on the Fragment. The spells need to be set only once. Inside the Player class they will be transformed into a map that I want to observe for changes in the Fragment.

Comment: Where do you "activate" the cooldown for the spell?